# Redirect non www to www in React JS

Tags: reactjs, redirect, web, webpack, server

When user enter http://example.com I would like to redirect them to http://www.example.com.

If I use nginx + php I can use below

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/html/example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    // skip some non related config
}
```

But what if I use react JS

```
 $ sudo npm start
```

And webpack.dev.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

var parentDir = path.join(__dirname, "../");

module.exports = {
    entry: [path.join(parentDir, "index.js")],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: parentDir + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: parentDir,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        disableHostCheck: true
    }
};

loaders: [{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }];
```

Can I achieve the same thing? I would like to redirect them in server side but not the client side. Thanks !

Comment: This has to be done on the server side.Check with ur server administrator.

Comment: @karthik I have not use nginx nor apache. I just use react JS + express. So I should config express JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `window.location` object to check current host name and redirect if not start with **www**

```
if (!window.location.host.startsWith("www")){
    window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + "www." + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
}
```

Comment: I agree this is the good client side method. But could I achieve this in server side? Much Thanks !

Comment: I think the stuff should be in React JS or webpack but not related to express. By the way I just use express to be API server.

Comment: if I was in your situation I will add this code in `index.js`

Comment: Thanks @ali I will use this method.

Comment: What about the opposite? if we want to redirect www to non-www?